# How do I write a public timer everyone sees the same?

Tags: java, android, timer, long-integer

I want to implement a Timer in my app which shows when the new update is comming out.
Importand is that everyone who uses my app sees the same timer with the same amount of hours remaining.

Does someone has an idea how I can archive that?

**UPDATE:**

I tried this so far:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm:ss");
        formatter.setLenient(false);


        String endTime = "11.10.2019, 15:23:00";

        Date endDate;
        try {
            endDate = formatter.parse(endTime);
            timer = endDate.getTime();

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        diff = timer - startTime;


        new CountDownTimer(timer, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                startTime=startTime-1;
                long serverUptimeSeconds =
                        (millisUntilFinished - startTime) / 1000;




                String  hms =  (String.format("%d", serverUptimeSeconds / 86400)+"d "+String.format("%d", (serverUptimeSeconds % 86400) / 3600)+"h "+ String.format("%d", ((serverUptimeSeconds % 86400) % 3600) / 60))+"m " + String.format("%d", ((serverUptimeSeconds % 86400) % 3600) % 60)+"s ";
                counter.setTitle(hms);

            }
```

It shows the remaining time depending on the date and time I write in

```
String endTime = "11.10.2019, 15:23:00";
```

and on the users timezone.

How can I archive that everyone sees the remaining time NOT based on their timezone but on my time zone: GMT+2?

Comment: Do you mean `same amount of hours remaining` independent from the timezone of the user? One way could be: the app get the update time from your webpage and starts based on this information the timer for the user. btw. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @SubOptimal I updated my question. Yes I mean independent from the timezone of the user

Answer (score 0):

You can get time in only one timezone. And all user will see same result of time, independent from the timezone of the user

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+02:00");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(tz);
String time = String.format("%02d" , c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY))+":"+
        String.format("%02d" , c.get(Calendar.MINUTE))+":"+
        String.format("%02d" , c.get(Calendar.SECOND))+":"+
        String.format("%03d" , c.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
```

Comment: How can I add this to my code so that my timer is taking the informations from "c"